# How to join external tables with a shapefile's attribute table in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

I need to join a .csv table into an attribute table of a shapefile. I wanted to do this with QGIS and i don't seem to find anyway of doing it. I know that the mmqgis plugin does it, but my shapefile has 6000 records and this plugin crashes at 2000 and something...
Any ideas?

Comment: I must be missing a plugin. I have the Ftools loaded, but only "Join attributes by location". Is there an additional step?

Comment: Like it was written, it's a tab in the Layer Properties window. Please open a separate question next time, since this is not an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In QGIS 1.7 you'll find Table Joins in Layer Properties. Load the CSV file using "Add vector layer".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thats one way if the csv file has location data. I think you should also be aware that |VECTOR|DATA MANAGEMENT TOOLS|JOIN ATTRIBUTES will join non-located data to an existing GIS layer. For instance you have a road layer which was created only with a name attribute. In another data table you have names and road surface but no location data. The join field will be the name attribute, and the output layer will have a new attribute showing road surface. This new layer can then be symbolised to display road surface. 
In JOIN ATTRIBUTES the dialog asks for a dbf file but .csv files are also supported.

If you need to manipulate your join attribute to ensure the values are identical, open the csv and the dbf of the shapefile in LibreOffice and manipulate them there.

Cannot comment on the number of records supported by DATA MANAGEMENT TOOLS

You may have to turn on the F-TOOLS plugin.

hth

Comment: Or maybe I am still using the dinosaur method.....

Comment: The .csv file does not have to contain location data to be loaded using "Add vector layer". (The naming is misleading.)