# Automating the updating of the attribute table of a shapefile that is linked to a CSV file

Tags: pyqgis

I know this has been discussed before, and I used the code provided by **@Joseph** in [How to join data from excel to an attribute table in QGIS without creating duplicates](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/187067/84870) for my Macros.

I am trying to achieve what @Joseph said, but I am attaching a screenshot of the error that I got when I did what you said. Below is my complete macros code.

'**Noviembre_P01**' is my shapefile
'**project_2_gis_mapping.csv**' is the csv file that I want to be able to connect automatically to this shapefile so that whenever my csv is updated, the attribute table in the shapefile also updates itself.
'LOC_CODE' is the common attribute to my .shp and .csv files.
'**first_bloo**' and '**diagnosis**' are the 2 fields I am interested in mainly, out of all the fields in the csv file.

I also **did not** create a join like he mentioned.

Conversely, will using 'Watch File' in the 'Add Delimited Text Layer' dialogue box server the exact same purpose?

```
def openProject(): from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import qgis
from qgis.core import QgsMapLayerRegistry, QgsVectorJoinInfo

for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    # Change to your shapefile name
    if layer.name() == "Noviembre_P01":
        qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(layer)
        shp = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()

for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    # Change to your csv name
    if layer.name() == "project_2_gis_mapping.csv":
        qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(layer)
        csv = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()

# Set up join parameters
shpField='LOC_CODE'
csvField='LOC_CODE'
joinObject = QgsVectorJoinInfo()
joinObject.joinLayerId = csv.id()
joinObject.joinFieldName = csvField
joinObject.targetFieldName = shpField
shp.addJoin(joinObject)

# Define fields to update and joined fields to copy values from
ip1 = shp.fieldNameIndex('first_bloo') 
ip1_join = shp.fieldNameIndex('project_2_gis_mapping.csv_first_bloo')
ip2 = shp.fieldNameIndex('diagnosis') 
ip2_join = shp.fieldNameIndex('project_2_gis_mapping.csv_diagnosis')

shp.startEditing()
for feat in shp.getFeatures():
    shp.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(), first_bloo, feat.attributes()[first_bloo_join])
    shp.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(), diagnosis, feat.attributes()[diagnosis_join])
shp.commitChanges()

# Remove join 
shp.removeJoin(csv.LOC_CODE())
    pass
```

[image: Screenshot of Error Message]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the last line of code: `pass`. You can simply remove it as it is not needed in this situation (it is [mainly useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22612774/7635569) with empty functions).

And to explain the error, Python expects all code to be properly [indented](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation). The faulty last line is indented more than the previous line and it is not part of a logical group.

Comment: Thanks for replying; I removed the last line, but I am still getting an error. I don't know how to attach the screenshot of that here, but it says " NameError: name 'csv' is not defined". I cross-checked the name of my csv file and it is the same as that previously mentioned in my Macros script. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your post and paste the complete error message. It contains useful info, such as the line at which the error occurs