# Visualisation: probabilistic rainfall forecast from CSV

Tags: qgis, csv, visualisation

Note: I have a basic idea of how shapefiles work & how to save maps as images.

I'm a super noob on QGIS. I have this CSV which provides me details such as

- State
- Average rainfall (mm)
- Probability % - Levels
  (Normal,Above,Low)

Sample Data:

[image: This is what my data looks like]

How can I visualise this on a map using QGIS? Please direct me to source on how to use the above dataset on QGIS & how to plot a legend alongside it. (I have the shapefiles of the states)

Comment: Do you have access to a US States Shapefile? Then you can Join State Name from each data set and display in QGIS. see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182281/joining-data-from-excel-to-attribute-table-in-qgis-without-creating-duplicates

Comment: @Mapperz I do have the US States Shapefile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first you should remove the second line in your CSV file. So your first line looks like:

```
State;Average rainfall;Probability Below;Probability Normal;Probability Above
```

use comma instead of semicolon if you are using american format.

Now load this CSV into QGIS like this: Layer --> Add Layer --> Add delimited Text layer:

[image]

Choose the settings you need.

Now you need a Georeferenced file of the states. Like a Shapefile. Add it and perform a join:

[image]

To make this join permanent, export your layer as new file.

You can now visualize your data in symbology tab:

[image]

*using a weird example here as I'm too lazy to create new data, but you should get the point*

Comment: Thank you very much for this! Also, does this visualise a different set of legends for Probability % - Levels (Normal, Above, Low) @MrXsquared ?

Comment: This depends on your styling rules. Set it up as you wish it to have.