Converting CSV to MultiPolygon shapefile in QGIS
I have a MultiPolygon shapefile and the attribute table looks like this.

The district names and state names are jumbled with special characters. I know I can use the replace function in the Field Calculator to rectify this but I have to change some of the names altogether.
So to make the editing easier I exported the layer as a CSV file and made the necessary modifications in Excel. Now  I cannot import the CSV file again as a shapefile.
Since there is no x,y coordinate information, I tried the below option in add CSV layer (tried both shape_length and shape_area in the geometry field), but it is not working.


https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/186602/238751 might be related.

The link provided is with reference to joining a CSV file to a shapefile. I am aware of that procedure. What I want to know is, I am having a shapefile that needs extensive editing of the attributes which necessitates the use of Excel. In this case after editing it in Excel I want to import the entire CSV file as a MultiPolygon shapefile and not some few columns that can be done with join function.

More details please on "not working". And did you try a Join? What about that didn't work?

The geometry data does not, and cannot live in the dBase component. Editing a shapefile's dBase file with Excel is a recipe for disaster. Without knowing  each of the dozens of ways you could destroy the shapefile integrity, you should not attempt it. The solution to this antipattern is to use a join, then calculate changed values across using GIS software, which won't destroy the dataset.

@Vince did not understand right what you want to do. When you export the polygon shapefile into CSV you must select from "layer options" GEOMETRY=AS_WKT. By default geometries are not saved into CSV. Shape_area and shape_length do not contain geometries. See more info about AS_WKT option from https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/csv.html. When you have the geometries as WKT in the CSV file you can also import them back.

However, the right way to fix your issue would be to read the shapefile with correct character encoding.
