Classifying spatial data using QGIS
I have two files: geologie.dbf and Legenda_Geologie.xls. I need to classify some regions within the area that I am studying but I am not exactly sure how to do that.
Do I need to manually type the values there, in the Symbology Tab and hit Classify? If yes, then how do I know what values to type? Do I use those .dbf and .xls files? Do I import them and the software can classify everything automatically?
Those .dbf and .xls files contain so many inputs. Although there is information for the whole country, I need data for my area of study.
These are the images:
]1



You need to find a common property/column in those two data (.dbf and .xls files). It can be area name, number, or something identifying the data. Based on that field you can join the datasets together, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182281/ or https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins.html for examples.

Thank you for your answer! I will do that.

First I think you should step back and decide what your objective is. Do you want to classify by rock type, by age, by formation, etc, etc. After that decision, then you can decide whether the coding in the 2 files is likely to give you what you want or whether you have to apply some geological input to combine or group various codes.

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. If your Question has a litany of questions in it, it is more likely to be closed as lacking focus.
